# "RFC7474 : cross-protocol replay attack", what is it?

Tags: ospf, rfc

can someone please tell me what the "cross-protocol replay attack for protocols sharing common keys" refers to in the RFC7474?

Indeed, in the case of an extern attacker, he does not know any of the key shared by any protocol normally.
And in the case of an internal attacker (who compromised a router), the attacker knows Ko and the protocol identifier normally, so it means he can generate all Ks used.

thanks for any consideration,

Comment: I think it is clearly explained in the RFC's  first section: _1. Introduction_. What does the introduction say that you don't understand?

Comment: I clearly understand the concept of replay attacks (sending outdated logged information). What i don't understand is the principle of "cross-protocol", does it refers to multiple instances of OSPF on the same link? (i thought it is availbale in OSPFv3 but not in OSPFv2) In this case, that means that one packet sent for one instance may be interpreted for each instance of the protocol as valid due to authentication.  Please correct me if i'm wrong. Could you maybe provide some kind of exploitation scenario of a "cross-protocol replay attack"? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "cross-protocol" refers to multiple protocols that may use the same key. This can be common because people are lazy, and it is easy to use the same key for different things.

If you have an OSPF router on a broadcast medium, it will send its packets to every device on the medium, and it will listen to every device on the medium. A device that runs a different protocol could try the key used by that protocol to attack OSPF. If OSPF uses the same key, there could be a problem.

[*RFC 7474, Security Extension for OSPFv2 When Using Manual Key Management*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7474#section-6) addresses this:

> **6.  Mitigating Cross-Protocol Attacks**
>
> In order to prevent cross-protocol replay attacks for protocols
> sharing common keys, the two-octet OSPFv2 Cryptographic Protocol ID is
> appended to the authentication key prior to use.  Refer to the IANA
> Considerations (Section 9).

Comment: alright, i think i almost got it. However, i don't understand how such a preventive mesure can successfully protect from retrieving the OSPF key if len(Ks) <= len (H).